# Building array key chain

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to take an array of values, for example:

```
$index = array('0' => '1', '1' => '4', '2' => '7');
```

And use this to update the position of another array at position `$update['1']['4']['7']`?

I thought maybe I could do something like the below (but it seems that I can't)...

```
for($build_key=0;$build_key<3; $build_key++){
    $this_key .= "[".$index[$build_key]."]";
}
$update.$this_key = 'new data in';
```

**Update**

I'm not sure how many levels the array will have, which is why I've tried to use a for loop (i've put '3' above in the for loop though maybe i should have used count($index) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
$x = $index[0];
$y = $index[1];
$z = $index[2];

$update[$x][$y][$z] = 'new data in';
```

This will work for any length array:

```
$index = array('0' => '1', '1' => '4', '2' => '7');
$where = &$update;

foreach ($index as $key => $value)
    $where = &$where[$value];      

$where = 'new data in';
```

Comment: something like that, but i don't know how deep the array could be - it could be 3 levels it could be 10

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending strings, you could just keep a reference to the current array you're looking at:

```
$target =& $update;

for($build_key=0; $build_key < 3; $build_key++){
 $target =& $target[$index[$build_key]];
}

$target = 'new data';
```

Of course if `$index` is always going to be 3 elements long, it'd be easier to just hardcode it!